# WindowMargins exact CurrentValue

Tags: front-end, notebooks

Is there a way to force getting the numerical values of `WindowMargins` instead of `Automatic` for a window?

For example let say I want to create a new Notebook that is $62$ pixels below and $62$ pixels to the right of the current `EvalutaionNotebook`. If I run the following it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't depending on the window position on the current screen.

```
x = CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], "WindowMargins"];
NotebookPut[Notebook[{
   Cell["Some text.", "Text"]}],
 WindowMargins -> {
   {x[[1, 1]] + 62, Automatic},
   {Automatic, x[[2, 2]] + 62}
   }
 ]
```

For example sometimes the expression throws an error and results in the following because *Mathematica* is returning a different answer.

```
 {{131, Automatic}, {Automatic, 62 + Automatic}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`AbsoluteCurrentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AbsoluteCurrentValue.html) should do what you want:

```
AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], "WindowMargins"]
(* {{624, -2}, {-47, -19}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.   I should have checked the docs (Both Google and Mathematica.stackexchange.com turned up nothing in my initial search).  Oh well silly me.